# How to build executable JavaFx Jar File

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

Building a JavaFx jar file with interllij Ultimate with JDK 16 and Javafx 14.
I found a video on yutube which you have to create a different java class without extending it to Application and creating an artifact using that class as the main before building the App.
Problem:
When i use only one fxml and use the above method it works great.
But
When a create sub packages and more fxml files than this error show:
Error: Could not find or load main class Execte Class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Execte Class

Any Solution to this or any other way to do this. link and Video would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If your Execte class is in a package, you need to specify the fully qualified class name as the main class:  com.example.application.Execte